# javax.validation.validationException : At least one custom message must be created

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsf

according to checkCase constraint validator written in hibernate JSR 303 chackCase [contraintValidator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints-constraintannotation)

```
public boolean isValid(Group group, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    boolean isValid = false;
    ...

    if(!isValid) {
        constraintContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        constraintValidatorContext
            .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( "{my.custom.template}" )
            .addNode( "myProperty" ).addConstraintViolation();
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

applying this validator in JSF using `<f:validateBean>` will result in this exception :
javax.validation.validationException : At least one custom message must be created if default error message gets disabled
while using this validator

```
package com.mycompany;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CheckCaseValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckCase, String> {

    private CaseMode caseMode;

    public void initialize(CheckCase constraintAnnotation) {
        this.caseMode = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {

        if (object == null)
            return true;

        if (caseMode == CaseMode.UPPER)
            return object.equals(object.toUpperCase());
        else
            return object.equals(object.toLowerCase());
    }

}
```

without **constraintValidatorContext** will give a message in `<h:messages>`

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: the question is how can i show up my built message in <h:messages> after disabling the default message since without that code (disabling default message and building own message) constraintContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation(); constraintValidatorContext .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( "{my.custom.template}" ) .addNode( "myProperty" ).addConstraintViolation();       the default message is show in <h:messages>

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that validate() in the validator returns false but no message has been created. You have to add one like this:

```
if (some condition) {
    constraintContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("something is wrong")
            .addConstraintViolation();
    return false;
}
return true;
```